# How do you get Feathersjs offline-realtime syncing working with aurelia-cli

Tags: feathersjs, aurelia

Windows 10 x64
aurelia-cli 0.31.3
feathers-client 2.3.0
feathers-offline-realtime 0.1.2

I am trying to get [feathers-offline-realtime](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/offline-first/configure-realtime.html) to work with [aurelia-cli](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli) but I keep getting error.

------- File not found or not accessible ------

Location: D:/Development/animals-r-people-too/just-shelter/client/node_modules/feathers-offline-realtime/lib/commons/utils.js
Make sure that it is configured in aurelia.json and that it is not a Node.js package

Calling page
import realtime from 'feathers-offline-realtime'

I have added feathers-offline-realtime to aurelia.json

```
         {
            "name": "feathers-offline-realtime",
            "main": "index",
            "path": "../node_modules/feathers-offline-realtime/lib",
            "resources": []
          },
       {
        "name": "feathers-commons",
        "main": "index",
        "path": "../node_modules/feathers-commons/lib",
        "deps": ["utils"],
        "resources": []
      },
                {
        "name": "utils",
        "main": "index",
        "path": "../node_modules/feathers-commons/commons/utils",
        "resources": []
      },
```

Using webpack (non aurelia-cli) just requiring feathers-offline-realtime works fine.